# Using Azure IoT - telemetry from a Windows desktop application

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I work for a company that manufactures large scientific instruments, with a single instrument having 100+ components: pumps, temperature sensors, valves, switches and so on. I write the WPF desktop software that customers use to control their instrument, which is connected to the PC via a serial or TCP connection. The concept is the same though - to change a pump's speed for example, I would send a "command" to the instrument, where an FPGA and custom firmware would take care of handling that command. The desktop software also needs to display dozens of "readback" values (temperatures, pressures, valve states, etc.), and are again retrieved by issuing a "command" to request a particular readback value from the instrument.

We're considering implementing some kind of telemetry service, whereby the desktop application will record maybe a couple of dozen readback values, each having its own interval - weekly, daily, hourly, per minute or per second.

Now, I could write my own telemetry solution, whereby I record the data locally to disk then upload to a server (say) once a week, but I've been wondering if I could utilise Azure IoT for collecting the data instead. After wading through the documentation and concepts I'm still none the wiser! I get the feeling it is designed for "physical" IoT devices that are directly connected to the internet, rather than data being sent from a desktop application?

Assuming this is feasible, I'd be grateful for any pointers to the relevant areas of Azure IoT. Also, how would I map a single instrument and all its components (valves, pumps, etc) to an Azure IoT "device"? I'm assuming each component would be a device, in which case is it possible to group multiple devices together to represent one customer instrument?

Finally, how is the collected data reported on? Is there something built-in to Azure, or is it essentially a glorified database that would require bespoke software to analyse the recorded data?

Comment: I do recommend to read the documents such as the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/overview-iot-plug-and-play and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/overview-iot-central

Comment: I am adding more documents related to your scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/about-iot-edge?view=iotedge-2020-11, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart?view=iotedge-2018-06, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/?view=iotedge-2020-11, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-as-gateway?view=iotedge-2020-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure IoT would give you:

- Device SDKs for connecting (MQTT or AMQP), sending telemetry, receiving commands, receiving messages, reporting properties, and receiving property update requests.
- An HA/DR service (IoT Hub) for managing devices and their authentication, configuring telemetry routes (where to route the incoming messages).
- Service SDKs for managing devices, sending commands, requesting property updates, and sending messages.

> If it matches your solution, you could also make use of the Device Provisioning Service, where devices connect and are assigned an IoT hub. This would make sense, for instance, if you have devices around the world and wish to have them connect to the closest IoT hub you have deployed.

Those are the building blocks. You'd integrate the device SDK into your WPF app. It doesn't have to be a physical device, but the fact it has access to sensor data makes it behave like one and that seems like a good fit. Then you'd build a service app using the Service SDKs to manage the fleet of WPF apps (that represent an instrument with components, right?). For monitoring telemetry, it would depend on how you choose to route it. By default, it goes to an EventHub instance created for you. You'd use the EventHub SDK to subscribe to those messages. Alternatively, or in addition to, those telemetry messages could be routed to Azure Storage where you could perform historical analysis. There are other [routing options](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c).

Does that help?